# How can I say "Do something in exchange" in a different way?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I'd like to know alternative ways to say: "Do something in exchange" when someone helps me. If possible can you guys give me three or more examples?

**For example,**

> "Thanks for helping, **what can I do in exchange?**"

Could I say "**Do something back**" (I don't know if it's grammatically right) to show my appreciation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there something I can do in return?

> [do] something in return [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/something+in+return)

Comment: Yes, *return a favor*: "How can I return your favor?"

Answer (score 1):

**May I return the favor?**

or

**Can I reimburse you, somehow?**

or

**Let me know if you need anything.**

or

**What do I owe you?**

or

**I owe you one.**

Answer (score 0):

A bit more tersely, I tend to use [to reciprocate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reciprocate) when describing such an action.

> - to do (something) for or to someone who has done something similar for or to you
> - to have (a feeling) for someone who has the same feeling for you

However, when specifically talking to the person in an informal setting, it seems a bit easier to just speak about "returning the favor".